# Less.js setting file property to 'to.css' in sourcemap

Tags: less

so using lessc(2.7.2) compiler and the the following

`less.render(data, {
    filename: entryFile,
    plugins: [autoprefixPlugin],
    compress: true,
    sourceMap: {
        sourceMapURL: '/static/extensions/css/index.css.map',
        sourceMapBasepath: 'project/web/webroot/',
        sourceMapRootpath: '/',
        outputSourceFiles: true,
        sourceMapFullFilename: '/static/extensions/css/index.css'
    }
})`

It generates a CSS/map string which are then written to files. now I've worked out most of the setting, but I'm still getting one issue.
In the .map file, the property "file" is set to "to.css".

I understand why, the compiler does not know the name of the file as it's not written yet, but I can't find anything in the docs about this either.

Am I missing an option?

Comment: Sourcemaps known to not work properly with postprecessing plugins (`autoprefixer` and `clean-cs`s in this case) that try to modify these sourcemaps on their own. In your particular case above I'd say this `"to.css"` is most likely set by the `autoprefixer` not by Less. For that reason I'd suggest you to not put such plugins in programmatic scripts but to use the corresponding libraries directly (pros: more recent version, more control over their options incl. sourcemaps).

Comment: So what is your result w/o `[autoprefixPlugin]`? (and do not use `compress: true` - it's deprecated... use any CSS minifyer instead - e.g. `clean-css`).

Comment: And finally I've just realized I can't see any [`sourceMapOutputFilename`](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/v2.7.2/bin/lessc#L312) in your snippet (i.e. it's usually a good idea to use `lessc` source code as reference for programmatic options).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I was missing that! thanks, in the docs it lists these as the only properties:
`The sourceMap option is an object which enables you to set sub sourcemap options. Available sub options are: sourceMapURL,sourceMapBasepath,sourceMapRootpath,outputSourceFiles and sourceMapFileInline. `

Would you like to submit as an answer?

Comment: So that was it? (I simply don't use sourcemaps so I never sure what particular option do, so I can only guess from sources). Feel free to answer yourself (I'll upvote) - I think you could formulate it better than me.